# How to get html of current jssor slide

Tags: jquery, jssor

How do I get the HTML of the current active slide in jssor slider?

JS

```
var options = { $AutoPlay: true };
var event_slider = new $JssorSlider$('slide-container', options);

event_slider.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_PARK,function (slideIndex,fromIndex) {
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="slide-container">
    <div u="slides" id="slides">
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="image1.jpg">
            <div class="slide-data">
                <div class="slide-id">5</div>
                <div class="slide-title">Slide Title</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using any framework on your page or you need to get the slide with native javascript?

Comment: Nothing other than jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Ok you could easily get the slides doing (this will return the first one):

```
$('.slide-data').html()
```

You should inspect the element using firebug of equivalent do find out about the active one though.
Usually there is a css class. Let's say it's .active, then it would become:

```
$('.slide-data.active').html()
```

**Edit:**
More complex than I thought. 
I had a look on the website of the plugin and the only information you have to know what is the current slide is, it's that the position left is 0px
You can try something like this:

```
$('#slide-container div[u=slides]').(function(){ 
  return $(this).css('left') == 0 
}).html();
```

This would take all children of slide-container, which are div, contains u=slides attribute and own left 0px property.

Comment: An 'active' class doesn't seem to be added to the slide when it becomes active, just inline styles.

Comment: $('.slide-data').eq(slideIndex).html()